# CDK Synth With NodejsFunction Bundling Error - Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing

Tags: typescript, npm, aws-lambda, npm-install, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to use AWS CDK to create a Lambda, from which I am encountering this error:

*"npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing."*

It then errors with *"Missing: [PACKAGE NAME] from lock file"* for all the packages.

**Lambda Folder:**

```
- helpers
- node_modules
- index.ts
- LambdaFunction.test.ts
- package.json
- package-lock.json
```

**My actions:**

1. I have successfully installed all `node-modules` by traversing into the Lambda folder, and running "npm install". No errors were shown in the terminal.
2. I have added the packages I need into `bundling.nodeModules` within the `NodejsFunction` function props.
3. Within the `package.json` file, I have ensure `"type": "module"`
4. I've removed all code from the Lambda-handler function besides the shell of `export async function handler(event: any, context: object) {}` and receive the error still

**Stack Code:**

```
const lambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, `intoNSQueueConsumer`, {
  ...defaultProps,
  description: "description",
  entry: join(__dirname, "../src/lambda-handlers/lambdaFunction/index.ts"),
  environment: {
    ENVIRONMENT: context.environment,
  },
  bundling: {
    nodeModules: ["axios", "axios-retry", "crypto-js"], // Need to be installed
    externalModules: ["aws-sdk"], //already available in the runtime
  },
});
```

***EDIT***

1. Removing all node-modules and installing any one of the packages causes the error. Therefore, it is not package-dependent.
2. [Here are the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html) for the `NodejsFunction`

Comment: I've checked all my lambdas and I don't have ```"type": "module"``` anywhere. I actually had this error multiple times already. I'm using ```esbuild``` for my lambdas. The solution was to update the ```esbuild``` dependency in the CDK App ```package.json``` and in the lambda ```package.json``` to the same version.

Comment: My understanding is that `esbuild` is only for the root directly `package.json` file. Where did you read it is for the lamda `package.json` file? Thanks for your initial comments. @ExceptionNotThrownException

Comment: It is the way it works for me. I can remember I've struggeled much with the bundling, but I can't tell You where I've read that. Was probably more or less voodoo programming.
Tell me if that works for You, otherwise we may think about some other solutions.

Comment: @ExceptionNotThrownException, same error unfortunately. It's annoying because I have another function that works and bundles perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this error is to add the `depsLockFilePath` like so in the `new NodejsFunction` props:

`depsLockFilePath: join(__dirname, "../src/lambda-handlers/lambdaFunction/package-lock.json"),`

More information about it can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs.NodejsFunction.html#depslockfilepath).

Comment: Good to know, actually I dont have this line added, but everything works fine. I keep this in mind tho, can be helpful later. Thanks!